# Getting 1970-01-01 after converting int to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an attribute like:

```
df. CalculationDateKey.head()
0    20201231
1    20201130
2    20201031
3    20200930
4    20200831
Name: CalculationDateKey, dtype: int64
```

And I want to convert it into datetime.

I tried:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['CalculationDateKey']).head()
```

which yields:

```
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00.020201231
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.020201130
2   1970-01-01 00:00:00.020201031
3   1970-01-01 00:00:00.020200930
4   1970-01-01 00:00:00.020200831
Name: CalculationDateKey, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want this, so I can calculate difference in months between two dates.

Answer (score 2):

Don't let Pandas infer your date format so specify it:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['CalculationDateKey'], format='%Y%m%d')
0   2020-12-31
1   2020-11-30
2   2020-10-31
3   2020-09-30
4   2020-08-31
Name: CalculationDateKey, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you try to convert integers to dates using [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), Pandas default unit is nanoseconds (since January 1, 1970). That's why you're getting values like 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0**20201231** as a result.

As Corralien mentioned in their answer, you can pass a date format string to let Pandas know the correct way to interpret those `YYYYmmdd` values.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['CalculationDateKey'],  format='%Y%m%d')
```